# How to stop the Parallel for loop process outside the loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel.for

I start the parallel for loop process from `button click(Start Button)`. The parallel process going well but at the time I moved another page then I return to current parallel process page,process going well.

I try to stop the Parallel process from another `button click(button stop)`. Is it possible?

```
protected void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      Parallel.For(0, dtrecord.Rows.Count, pOptions1, (j, pls) =>
         {               
            if (Session["Stop"] != null)
            {
               pls.Stop();
               Session.Remove("Stop2");
               Session["ParallelStopped"] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               Checkrecords(dtrecord, ImportFileID, j);
            }
         });
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Log.Trace("Error occured in btnstop_Click");
      Log.Error(ex.Message);
   }
}

protected void btnstop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      Session["Stop"] = 1;

      Session.Remove("start");
      Session["start"] = null;

      BindImportfileDetails();
      BindImportrecordsdetails(hidimid.Value);
      bindimportrecords();
      Getrecordstatuscount();
      Log.Trace("User has been stopping the import process");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Log.Trace("Error occured in btnstop_Click");
      Log.Error(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Although it can be improved, it theoretically should prevent **new** executions from running. Also, `Session["ParallelStopped"] = 1;` should probably be after the `Parallel.For` (it blocks)

Comment: @Rob In button click event created session["Stop"] .But I can't  get the Session["Stop"] value in parallel loop. If I check in page load it's get the Session["Stop"] value.

Comment: A minor point: in `btnstart_Click` you have `"Error occured in btnstop_Click"`.

Comment: @PJTraill No error occurred in btnstop_click

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET but in Winforms or WPF putting the Parallel.For on the UI thread like that would block the UI till it is done so clicking the stop button would look like nothing is happening.